# Python. Encontrar la palabra más corta de una lista usando split()

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa que busque la palabra más corta introducida por el usuario. Pero a la hora de mostrar la palabra más corta me muestra todas la palabras. En cambio la longitud de la palabra más corta me sale bien. ¿Alguien ve lo que estoy haciendo mal? ¡Ya no se me ocurre que más probar!

```
line = input("Ingresa una cadena: ")
words = line.split()
shortest = words[0]
for i in words:
    if len(words) < len(shortest):
        shortest = words
print("La palabra más corta: " + str(shortest))
print("La longitud de la palabra más corta: " + str(len(shortest)))
```

Comment: Dentro del bucle, es la variable `i` la que va tomando el valor de cada una de las palabras, y no es `words` (que es la lista completa). Por tanto es `len(i)` lo que debes usar para buscar la palabra más corta, y `shortest = i` para almacenarla. Y por cierto que para que el código sea más fácil de leer y comprender yo evitaría llamar `i` a una variable de bucle. Si la hubieras llamado `word` posiblemente no habrías cometido ese error :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ay! Los nombres!

La variable `i` contiene una palabra de la lista, pero nunca usas esa variable; todo el tiempo haces referencia a `words`, que es la lista completa.

He aquí la versión corregida:

```
line = input("Ingresa una cadena: ")
words = line.split()
shortest = words[0]
for palabra in words:
    if len(palabra) < len(shortest):
        shortest = palabra
print("La palabra más corta: " + str(shortest))
print("La longitud de la palabra más corta: " + str(len(shortest)))
```

Comment: Podrías reemplazar el bucle for por `shortest = min(words, key=len)`

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias. La idea era mostrarle la causa del error, mas que optimizarle el proceso.

Comment: De nada. Lo se, quería que también supiera que podía optimizar el proceso de ese modo, no cambiar la respuesta.

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias. La cosa es que era un programa a corregir con varios errores y no podía cambiar la estructura principal ni cambiar de nombres a las variables ni nada de eso (ni mucho menos quitar el bucle for ;-) )